# Error in calling python script from node.js

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am getting this error. So basically python script is getting called successfully from the nodejs function. However, since I am using "python-shell" to make the call, it is calling using the default version Python2.7. I have a function list.copy() in my python script which is an addition in Python3.x. How do I change the python version in "python-shell"

```
Error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'
    at PythonShell.parseError (/Users/neelkapadia/Desktop/NCSU/SE/WolfPlanner/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:184:17)
    at terminateIfNeeded (/Users/neelkapadia/Desktop/NCSU/SE/WolfPlanner/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:98:28)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/neelkapadia/Desktop/NCSU/SE/WolfPlanner/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:89:9)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
    ----- Python Traceback -----
    File "scheduler/core_scheduler.py", line 194, in <module>
      schedule = generate_schedule(unityId, day_date, student_record, buffer_time)
    File "scheduler/core_scheduler.py", line 87, in generate_schedule
      new_tasks = sorted_tasks.copy()
  traceback: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "scheduler/core_scheduler.py", line 194, in <module>\n    schedule = generate_schedule(unityId, day_date, student_record, buffer_time)\n  File "scheduler/core_scheduler.py", line 87, in generate_schedule\n    new_tasks = sorted_tasks.copy()\nAttributeError: \'list\' object has no attribute \'copy\'\n',
  executable: 'python',
  options: null,
  script: 'scheduler/core_scheduler.py'
```

P.S: The following is the node js code which calls python script.

```
module.exports = {
    call_python: function(unityId, buffer_time, day_date, callback){

    var options = {
        args: [unityId, day_date, buffer_time]
    };

    var shell = require('python-shell')

    shell.run('scheduler/core_scheduler.py', options, function (err, results) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log('results: %j', results);
        });
```

Comment: Please post code and error messages as `formatted text`, not images.

Comment: Specify `pythonPath`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell#running-a-python-script-with-arguments-and-options

Comment: @FeiXiang I put the code and error as text. I am a new user and didn't know about this. Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan I have to deploy the application. So how do I assign a fix `pythonpath` since it will be different for each user?

Comment: @NeelKapadia: Try just `python3`